# Issue migrating custom positional flat file schema from Seeburger to BizTalk

Tags: xml, csv, xsd, biztalk, data-integration

I am trying to migrate some positional flat file schemas from Seeburger to BizTalk and it seems I am stuck with a problem I do not know how to handle with BizTalk.

I'll try to reduce the complexity to the basic issue I am having.

Let's say that in Seeburger the following message is processed.

`Field1----Field2-------Field3----Field4--[CR][LF]`

I added padding character "-" here to be visible, and CR LF segment terminator

The seeburger schema has defined the following structure for the above message

Field1 = Min/Max length = 10 characters

Field2 = Min/Max length = 13 characters

Field3 = Min/Max length = 10 characters

Field4 = Min/Max length = 8 characters

All fields are optional so it may be possible to get a message like this only

`Field1----Field2-------Field3----[CR][LF]`

Until here everything works fine. The problem is that the actual messages received by Seeburger are looking like this for example:

`Field1----Field2-------Field3----Field4[CR][LF]`

or

`Field1----Field2-------Field3[CR][LF]`

Please notice that the padding characters are missing from the last element from the record. Seeburger knows to handle this but in BizTalk I am not able to validate a message like this. ( without last element length < length defined in schema )

Biztalk expects that the length of last field from the record to be the defined length in the schema which makes sense. I did tried a lot of things but I was not able to find a solution for this.

Was somebody else stuck on this or do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set the Early Termination flag to True on the schema root
   [image: Early Termination flag image]
2. Set the Early Terminate Optional Fields to Yes
   [image: Early Terminate Optional Fields]
3. Make sure all the fields that are optional have the Min Occurs set to 0

For an input file

```
Field1----Field2-------Field3----Field4--[CR][LF]
Field1----Field2-------Field3----Field4[CR][LF]
Field1----Field2-------Field3[CR][LF]
Field1----Field2-------[CR][LF]
Field1----Field2[CR][LF]
Field1----[CR][LF]
Field1[CR][LF]
```

The schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch2.Schema.SO73820633" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch2.Schema.SO73820633" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="true" early_terminate_optional_fields="true" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x0D 0x0A" child_order="postfix" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Record">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <recordInfo sequence_number="1" structure="positional" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Root_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="10" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Root_Child2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="13" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Root_Child3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="10" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Root_Child4" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="8" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Will parse it to below (XML tidied with Notepad++ for readability)

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch2.Schema.SO73820633">
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1>Field1----</Root_Child1>
        <Root_Child2>Field2-------</Root_Child2>
        <Root_Child3>Field3----</Root_Child3>
        <Root_Child4>Field4--</Root_Child4>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1>Field1----</Root_Child1>
        <Root_Child2>Field2-------</Root_Child2>
        <Root_Child3>Field3----</Root_Child3>
        <Root_Child4>Field4</Root_Child4>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1>Field1----</Root_Child1>
        <Root_Child2>Field2-------</Root_Child2>
        <Root_Child3>Field3</Root_Child3>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1>Field1----</Root_Child1>
        <Root_Child2>Field2-------</Root_Child2>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1>Field1----</Root_Child1>
        <Root_Child2>Field2</Root_Child2>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1>Field1----</Root_Child1>
    </Record>
    <Record xmlns="">
        <Root_Child1>Field1</Root_Child1>
    </Record>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thank you , indeed the early termination flag fixed my issue.